# How to implement a blinds toggle effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to write a "blinds" function that would close a DIV in a display:none mode. The unseen DIV is inside a wider DIV, containing the blind trigger.

This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle_blind").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Well, this blinds the button. How can I add a DIV to $this? Something like:

```
<div id="blind" class="wider_div">
   <h3 id="closeButton">Close</h3>
   <div style="display:none;" id="closeThis">
       <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I make the Close Button on H3 to close/open the CloseButton DIV on each click?

Comment: NB to readers: jQuery UI has had this implemented natively for over a decade: https://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div is the next sibling of the h3 so you can use .next()

E.g

```
$('#closeButton').click( function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Actually, one more question: Can I use this function in multiple DIVs? Trying to do so, gives functionality only to the first DIV; the rest are numb.

Comment: then use a class and the .live function

Answer (score 0):

Reference the div directly, you may put something else in between it and the h3.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#closeButton").click(function()
    {
        $("#closeThis").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```