# How to toggle a function for multiple divs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, toggle

I previously got [this (useful!) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316273/blind-with-jquery) about using .next() for a DIV "blinds" toggling effect.

However, I can't seem to get this simple function to work for more than one DIV at the same time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#closeButton").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are using is only selecting one element. You would need to change is to it selected a collection of elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wider_div h3").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

This might work given the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Is it about a specific type of button that occurs multiple times on a page? Try using jQuery's `live()`:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $('button.your_class').live('click', function (){
        $(this).toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

and attach the appropriate class to the buttons you want to 'be listened'.